# Jquery dont work inside ngview

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am working with angularjs and jquery(for menus and more), but I don't know why I can't make the jquery(eq. simple accordion menu) work like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySFX/trYR6/), all inside `<div ng-view>`, I tried all methods but this didn't work, please help me

this is my angular code

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute']);
        $url ="/load.php?stundent=<? echo $_GET["all"]; ?>";
           myApp.factory('myService',function($http){       
                     var getData = function() {
            return $http({method:"GET", url:$url}).then(function(result){
                return result.data;
            });
        };
        return { getData: getData };
    });


    myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl : 'main.html',
                    controller  : 'ItemsController'
                })
                // route for the home page
                .when('/one', {
                    templateUrl : 'one.html',
                    controller  : 'ItemsController'
                })

                // route for the about page
                .when('/two', {
                    templateUrl : 'p/two.html',
                    controller  : 'othercontroller'
                });
        });
    myApp.controller('othercontroller',  function othercontroller($scope,$http) {
    ...
    });

myApp.controller('ItemsController',  function ItemsController($scope,myService,$timeout,$http) { 
...
}
```

Comment: If you must use that jQuery ( can easily be done with angular) you need to put it in a directive. inside directive you have access to the main element and it's descendents

Comment: What "it doesn't work" mean? Please add details to your question about what you'd expect the code to do and what actually does.

Comment: the menu does not shrink, and when I click nothing happens

Comment: The markup inside `ng-view` is replaced when rendering template

Comment: i see the menu like this http://jsfiddle.net/trYR6/177/

Comment: @charlietfl please i can do it??

Comment: sure you can do it, inside a directive

Comment: you have a simple example please?

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery is optional for you, I suggest using UI Bootstrap or AngularStrap for such things. As others have stated, a custom directive will allow you to use jQuery. 
[Here's an example from another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59670/acceptable-way-of-using-jquery-methods-in-angular-directives)